# как узнать какие функции есть у dll в python

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

Я конечно в этом деле делаю только первые шаги, поэтому многого могу не понимать. Ну например, есть такая библиотека ctypes, с помощью нее можно манипулировать программами написанными на C, также и dll. Но вот представим ситуацию, хочу использовать какую-то библиотеку, к примеру KeyboardFilterCore.dll. И как мне понять, к каким функциям я могу обратиться, чтобы достичь нужного результата?

импортировав библиотеку KeyboardFilterCore.dll как мне понять, какими возможностями она обладает, какие функции есть, что они делают?

Comment: Прочитать в её документации.

Comment: согласен, но есть такие библиотеки на которые нету документации

Comment: В таком случае никак, только угадывать и, может, список [экспортированных символов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891493) посмотреть

Answer (score 0):

Ни как нельзя, dll зашифрованный файл.

Но у винды есть руководство, может там найдете нужную инфу.
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/learn/browse/?roles=developer&products=windows